# Journalist Looking For Physicist Entrepreneurs

Tags: discussion

My name is Eric Sokolsky and I do PR for Stack Exchange.  I came across a media opportunity that might be good for someone in the Physics community.

The reporter writes a regular career column for the national publication of the American Physical Society, APS News.  She is looking to interview people with physics degrees who are entrepreneurs. It doesn't matter whether you have a B.S., M.S., or Ph.D. in physics, but she wants to know how your physics degree has helped you launch your company. Early-stage to beyond IPO is fine.

This is an ongoing column, but her next deadline is 7:00pm EST *TODAY* (March 23).

If you think you fit the bill, please contact the reporter directly and put "physicist entrepreneurs" in the subject line.

It would also be great if in your introduction you could plug Stack Exchange - something like:  "Hi, my name is XXX, and my company is YYY, but I heard about this opportunity via Stack Exchange - a community-driven network of expert Q&A sites where experts share knowledge and answer complex technical questions.  You should check out the Physics site (physics.stackexchange.com) as well as the other 45 Stack Exchange sites - perhaps you'll find some interesting content for future stories."

Contact: 
Alaina Levine alaina@alainalevine.com

Good luck!!

Comment: There were some doubts about whether this question was legitimate but I have the official word from Rebecca that it is. Sorry for the misunderstanding Eric!

Comment: as the opportunity has passed, I'm closing this for now.